# Need help turning this LINQ expression into LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I need help in turning this linq expression into a linq statment. SampleData.Publishers and SampleData.Books are simple collections that I have from the Linq in Action book.

Here is the expression

```
var pubBooks =
            from pub in SampleData.Publishers
            join book in SampleData.Books on pub.Name equals book.Publisher.Name into pubbks
            select new {
                Publisher = pub.Name,
                Books =
                    from b in pubbks
                    select b.Title
            };
```

Here is what I have so far, but I can't seem to get the books collection defined in the anonymous type. Thanks for your time.

```
var pubBooks = SampleData.Publishers.Join(SampleData.Books, pub => pub.Name, book => book.Publisher.Name, (pub, book) => new {
            Publisher=pub.Name,
            Books=??????
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/) gave me this:

```
var pubBooks =
            SampleData.Publishers.GroupJoin(
                SampleData.Books,
                pub => pub.Name,
                book => book.Publisher.Name,
                (pub, pubbks) => new
                                     {
                                         Publisher = pub.Name,
                                         Books =
                                     from b in pubbks
                                     select b.Title
                                     });
```

Comment: I take no credit for this :-)
Someone should write an online LINQ-expression to statement conversion widget...

Comment: p.s. I didn't test it, obviously.

Answer (score 3):

Really easy way to do that is to use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). When you analyze your code you will see statement, not an expression.

Answer (score 3):

Another good way to transform this is to use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`GroupJoin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297.aspx).

I didn't test this but it could look like this:

```
var pubBooks = SampleData.Publishers.GroupJoin(SampleData.Books, pub => pub.Name, book => book.Publisher.Name, (pub, bookColl) => new {
            Publisher = pub.Name,
            Books = bookColl.Select(b => b.Title)
        });
```